# Квадратные скобки pip install

Tags: python, pip

Подскажите как называется и как реализуются выбор модулей при установке пакетов через pip

Например

```
pip install requests[socks]
```

Comment: Вы хотите определенный модуль из библиотеки взять или что?

Comment: не совсем понятно. При чем тут вообще квадратные скобки и какая проблема должна быть решена?

Comment: я решал проблему отсутствия информации

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это называется extras_require и описывается в setup.py устанавливаемого модуля. Напрмиер у requests это описано так

```
setup(
    ...
    extras_require={
        "security": [],
        "socks": ["PySocks>=1.5.6, !=1.5.7"],
        "use_chardet_on_py3": ["chardet>=3.0.2,<6"],
    },
    ...
)
```